# MS-BI-SSRS,Passing Cascaded parameters to Drill Through report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to develop a report from cube,and it has one drill through report.when i click on sales amount field on main report,then it open the drill through report with details.Here i passed the **(category,subcat,product)parameters(Cascaded)** to drill through report in action part of main report.In my main report i have two columns .
columns are **Level**  and              **Salesamount**.   Values are like
**[-]category**              **100**
    **[-]subcat**             **50**
         **product**          **30**
when i click on 100, parameters are passed & it open the detail report correctly, but when i click on 50,the values for subcat parameter is not getting values in detail report and same as the product also.
Here i used the expressions in parameter values
**pCategory**----iif(inscope(category),!fields.category.value,split(join(Parameters!category.value,","),","))

**psubcat**----iif(inscope(subcat),!fields.subcat.value,split(join(Parameters!subcat.value,","),","))

**pproduct**----iif(inscope(product),!fields.product.value,split(join(Parameters!product.value,","),","))

can any one plz reply me.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After Struggled 2 days , finally i made this. I just changed the expressions for the parameters, it worked fine.

pCategory= iif(inscope(category),!fields.category.value,split(join(Parameters!category.value,","),","))

psubcat= iif(inscope(subcat),!fields.subcat.value, lookupset(Fields!Category_ID.Value,Fields!Subcat_ID.Value,Fields!Subcat.Value,"dsMain")

pproduct= iif(inscope(product),!fields.product.value, lookupset(Fields!Subcat_ID.Value,Fields!Product_ID.Value,Fields!Product.Value,"dsMain")